# XPath search element by child value

Tags: python, xml, xpath

I've got a XML with following structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-2"?>
<partners>
  <partner>
    <id>001</id>
    ...
  </partner>
  <partner>
    <id>002</id>
    ...
  </partner>
  ...
</partners>
```

I want to search for a partner with a given id, using XPath. I'm using python [xml.etree](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xpath-support), but this may be irrelevant in this case. So far I'm trying: `'./partner[/id = "001"]'` to find a partner that has id=`001`:

```
for e in doc.findall('./partner[/id = "001"]'): print e
```

and this throws a syntax error of `SyntaxError: expected path separator ([)`, full stack trace below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 647, in findall
    return self._root.findall(path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 355, in findall
    return ElementPath.findall(self, path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/xml/etree/ElementPath.py", line 198, in findall
    return _compile(path).findall(element)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/xml/etree/ElementPath.py", line 176, in _compile
    p = Path(path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/xml/etree/ElementPath.py", line 93, in __init__
    "expected path separator (%s)" % (op or tag)
SyntaxError: expected path separator ([)
```

Can anybody point me what am I doing wrong?

---

*edit*: I'm afraid that it's due to python 2.6.8 version used. The docs are slightly different in this case: https://docs.python.org/release/2.6.8/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html. And no, I can't update python version, unfortunately...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[XPath support of xml.etree.ElementTree is limited](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xpath-support). How about using lxml? using [`xpath` method](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#the-xpath-method)

```
>>> x = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-2"?>
... <partners>
...   <partner>
...     <id>001</id>
...   </partner>
...   <partner>
...     <id>002</id>
...   </partner>
... </partners>'''
>>>
>>> import lxml.etree
>>> root = lxml.etree.fromstring(x)
>>> root.xpath('.//partner[id/text()="001"]')
[<Element partner at 0x2e29090>]
```

Comment: fortunately, I've got this module installed on the server I've got to work on. Works fine!